# RG flow and Ricci flow

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, ricci-flow, renormalization

It looks like the Laplace operator in the nonlinear sigma model (say the Polyakov action) is different from  the Laplace-Beltrami operator, how can one get the Ricci flow as a low order approximation to the perturbative renormalization group flow?

The Lagrangian in the Polyakov action is the trace of the pullback metric $\phi^*g$, or induced metric $ \phi^*g_{\mu \nu}(x) = g_{ij}(\phi(x))  \partial_\mu \phi^i(x) \partial_\nu \phi^j(x) $ for $\phi: (\Sigma, \gamma) \rightarrow (M, g) $,

$S( g; \phi)  
=  \frac{T}{2} \int_\Sigma dvol \,\gamma^{\mu \nu} \phi^*g_{\mu \nu}               
=  - \frac{T}{2} \int_\Sigma dvol \, g_{ij}  \phi^i \partial^\mu\partial_\mu \phi^j $

The usual notations are $\Delta =  \partial^\mu \partial_\mu$ and $\Delta_g = Tr_g(- \Delta)$. But this $\Delta_g$ is obviously different from the
Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_g = g^{ij}\partial_i \partial_j$ in the Ricci flow.

Comment: you have to rescale time, see for example page 4 of http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~friedan/talks/flows/Friedan_2008.04.15_Banff.pdf

Comment: Yes, I get this rescaling part, my question is about the Laplacian...